Universal circuit with PRF: how does a encoded PRF looks like?
I would like to ask or find materials on what an encoded string of PRF that can be fed into a universal circuit looks like.
To illustrate, I would like to have an encoding of $f_{k}()$, denoted as $encode(f_{k}())$, then use a universal circuit to evaluate it on input $x$. i.e., universal-circuit $(encode(f_{k}()),x)$ = $f_{k}(x)$.
May I ask what does encoding of a keyed PRF: $encode(f_{k}())$ looks like?
Thanks in advance
